# what is the least value of $K>0$ such that $|\sin^2x-\sin^2y|≤K|x-y|$ for all numbers $x$ and $y$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**NBHM PhD Screening Test 2005 Analysis**

> What is the least value of $K>0$ such that    $|\sin^2x-\sin^2y|≤K|x-y|$  $\forall$ $x$,$y \in \mathbb R$

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Find $\max_x |(\sin^2)'(x)|$ (its $1$!).

Comment: @copper.hat: Is this fact useful: by the mean value we have $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|\leq |x-y|$?

Comment: @BabakSorouh: I don't think so, but there is a simple way of calculating the $K$ for differentiable functions.

Answer (score 7):

If $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $\lim_{h\to 0} |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}| = |f'(x)|$. Hence if $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $|h| < \delta$, then  $|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}| \geq |f'(x)|-\epsilon$, or equivalently, $|f(x+h)-f(x)| \geq |h|(|f'(x)|-\epsilon)$.

It follows that if $f$ is differentiable, then if $K$ is such that $f$ satisfies the bound $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq K |x-y|$, then we  must have $K \geq\sup_t |f'(t)|$. By the mean value theorem, we have $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq \sup_t |f'(t)| |x-y|$, hence the least value of $K$ that satisfies the bound is $\sup_t |f'(t)|$.

In the example above, $f(x) = \sin^2(x)$, hence $f'(x) = 2 \cos x \sin x = \sin (2x)$, and $\sup_t |f'(t)| = 1$. Hence $K=1$ is the least value of $K$ such that the bound holds.

Comment: I see now what you mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, but how can *T* solve this problem? :)  [I'm guessing this was an extremely poor way of referring to Taylor polynomials.]

Comment: I assumed that T was a mistyped I!

Comment: then we  must have $K \geq\sup_t |f'(t)|$. By the mean value theorem, Hello @copper.hat How do You get it from the above inequality? Please help me.

Comment: @copper.hat: Can we say the following: $|f(x+h)-f(x)| \leq |h|(|f'(x)|+\epsilon)$ and $f$ satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq K |x-y|$ then $K \geq\sup_t |f'(t)|$ and the rest follows?

Comment: @YadatiKiran: I'm not exactly sure what I was thinking when I wrote the above, if $|f(x)-f(y)| \le K|x-y|$ for all $x,y$ then you must have $K \ge \sup_t |f'(t)|$ just by taking limits. The mean value theorem shows that $\sup_t |f'(t)|$ is the smallest such value for $K$.